# Get push additional Data onesignal iOS (JS)

Tags: javascript, push, phonegap, onesignal

My app (html/JS with Cordova/Phonegap) gets push from the OneSignal system, everything works fine.

I send each time a small variable (additionalData) so that once the notification has been clicked my app opens and a specific action is done. This variabla is stocked into a sessionStorage var so it can be used everywhere i want on my app.

In my index.js, in onDeviceready i have :

```
    var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
        sessionStorage.setItem('pushToLoad', JSON.stringify(jsonData.notification.payload.additionalData.ADDITIONALVAR));
    };

    window.plugins.OneSignal
    .startInit("USER CODE")
    .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
    .endInit();
```

Then, in a file called function.js I simply analyze the variable and I do my actions according to its value.

Like:

```
if(sessionStorage.getItem('pushToLoad') == 'blabla') { do stuff }
```

On Android, everything works fine ! But on iOS my var is empty/null, i don't know why, ive tryed a lot of piece of code and nothing works.

```
alert('Push var > ' + sessionStorage.getItem('pushToLoad'));
```

It returns me "null" on iOS.

Thanks for you help.